# SAPUI5 Property mProperties is a private member of sap.ui.base.ManagedObject

Tags: view, properties, controller, sapui5

I am programming something in SAPUI5 with an oData model.

I need to get this value:

[image]

Which is declared in my view as Orgpf:

```
<HBox class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
                <Text class="titulo" id="tituloplanta" text="{i18n>tituloTablaPl} "/>
                <Text class="titulo" id="planta" text="{Orgpf}"/>
            </HBox>
```

When i check "Console" tab in Chrome, i get this:

[image]

Where mProperties has the text value i need.

So I tried to get that value writing this on my controller:

```
var a = this.getView().byId("planta").bindElement({
    path: "/CenTVSet('" + ip + "')"
});
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
var planta = oModel.oData;
value = this.byId("planta").getText();
```

But it doesn't show anything in console and shows this error pointing my code:

[image]

Is there any way to get through this and get that value from the controller?

**Edit:**

Trying to use `value = this.byId("planta").getText();`

It shows in the console but as an empty value:

[image]

Comment: Every line before `value = this.byId("planta").getText();` is completely unnecessary (esp. the `bindElement`). Please remove them and see if your code works

Comment: I did, and it just shows like an empty value in the console. I'll update my question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the solution I got, to get that value:

```
oModel.read("/CenTVSet('" + ip + "')",{
            success: function(oData, oRes){
                var einri = oData.Einri;
                var orgpf = oData.Orgpf;
                var oTable = that.getView().byId("tablaPacientes");
                var oBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
                
                var filter = new Filter({
                    path: "Orgna",
                    operator: FilterOperator.EQ,
                    value1: orgpf
                });
                
                oBinding.filter(filter);
                
                //numero de pacientes
                oBinding.attachDataReceived(function(oEvent){
                    var iLength = oEvent.getSource().getLength();
                    
                    var oViewModel = new JSONModel({npat: iLength});
                    that.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "view");
                    
                //  that.getView().byId("pat").setText(iLength);
                });
            },
            error: function(oError){
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [provided API](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Text%23methods/getText) to get the value from `text` property.

```
const value = this.byId("planta").getText();
```

With this you can work with the controls `text` value inside your controller.

Comment: I don't know why that doesn't work. When i try to do a console.log to see it, it shows up as empty...

Comment: can you update your post with some controller code? it depends when and where you try to get the value from that Text control. As you can see in your xml view the text property of your Text control is using data binding. So maybe you try to get the value before it is loaded by your model.

Comment: I updated it with more controller code. Thanks!!

Comment: In which of the controller's hook methods are you trying to read that value? Maybe you are trying to read the value too soon! You could try to read the value in the onAfterRendering() method

Comment: I tried to read it in the same method I was reading my local IP. I tried with onAfterRendering() method, and even if it shows up in the console even sooner, the problem is that it looks like empty (check the edit on my question). I think the problem isn't when it should appear but the fact that it looks like empty :/

Comment: So probably your binding is incorrect.... How do you bind the model to your view/element? Is it a named model?

Comment: as binding to a model and retrieving the data is an async task you should wait for the model to get the data before you try to access it. if you could provide more insight to your controller it would be much easier to point you into the right direction